# Understanding 2:286

Tags: soul

> Allah does not burden a soul beyond that it can bear

I found this quote while reading through some reddit threads of an Islamic community. I find it quite profound but I have a doubt what this suggests about searching for help.

If we are to struggle in something or fail, should we ask for help? Or should keep to ourselves and have a faith that we can overcome it?

Maybe for simple things we can overcome but what about issues like  permenabt medical ones?

Answer (score 2):

To understand this statement you need to understand the objective of our existence on earth and what is expected out of us. Allah has created us to worship him.

> And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. Quran
> (51:56)

What is worship?

> Shaykhul-Islaam Ibn Taymiyyah (d.728H) said:
>
> “Worship is obedience to Allaah by following that which He ordered
> upon the tongues of His Messengers.” He also said, “Worship is a
> comprehensive term covering everything that Allaah loves and is
> pleased with – whether saying, or actions, outward and inward.”

As part of worship you will be tested to separate the truthful from the wicked.

> ‘Do the people think that they will be left to say, “We believe” and
> they will not be tested? But We have certainly tested those before
> them, and Allah will surely make evident those who are truthful, and
> He will surely make evident those who are false.’ [Qur’an 29: 2-3]

**Example of a Test:**

Allah has forbidden consumption of pork. Now either we obey Allah by not eating it or disobey by eating.

**Now coming to your question "Allah does not burden a soul beyond that it can bear" means Allah is not going to hold you accountable for what you don't have control over. It also means Allah is not going to test a soul beyond its capacity.**

**Example**: You are caught up in a remote area or forest where nothing is available as food except pork and you are in a state of hunger. You may die of hunger if you don't consume food. In this case you are allowed to eat pork although it was forbidden originally. Hence in this case Allah will not hold you accountable.

> He has forbidden you only the Maitah (dead animals), and blood, and
> the **flesh of swine**, and that which is slaughtered as a sacrifice for
> others than Allâh (or has been slaughtered for idols, on which Allâh’s
> Name has not been mentioned while slaughtering). **But if one is forced
> by necessity without wilful disobedience nor transgressing due limits,
> then there is no sin on him.** Truly, Allâh is Oft-Forgiving, Most
> Merciful. Quran(2:173)

**Levels of testing. Each person is tested according to his capacity.**

> Sa’d ibn Abi Waqqas reported: I said, “O Messenger of Allah, which
> people are tested most severely?” The Messenger of Allah(ﷺ), said, “They are the prophets, then the next
> best, then the next best. A man is put to trial according to his
> religion. If he is firm in his religion, his trials will be more
> severe. If he is weak in his religion, he is put to trial according to
> his strength in religion. The servant will continue to be put to trial
> until he is left walking upon the earth without any sin.”
>
> Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2398